# what is the sum of the divisors of N which are not multiples of K.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I need help with this number theory problem, hope someone could explain me how to do it with an explanation please, thanks! Any tips for practice/learn this types of number theory problems?

Comment: I tried to look for a pattern but couldn't figure it out yet, I don't really know a lot about divisibility. I can get the sum of the divisors of N but any idea about getting the sum without multiples of k.

Comment: Where did this problem come from? Have you seen similar problems anywhere? How much do you know about number theory?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to show this (I'm not good with proofs, but here's an example.)

Find the sum of all divisors of $1200$ that are not multiples of $24$.

$1200=2^4 \times 3 \times 5^2$.

The sum of the divisors of $1200 = (2^0+2^1+2^2+2^3+2^4)(3^0+3)(5^0+5+5^2)(7^0)(11^0)...$, because we can choose from $0$ to $4$ factors of $2$, $0$ to $1$ factors of $3$, $0$ to $2$ factors of $5$, $0$ factors of 7... etc.

Because when you multiply, you pick one term out of each parenthesis per term generated in the expansion.

Anyways, the sum of the divisors = $(31)(4)(31)=3844$

$24=2^3 \times 3$

Any number containing these factors is a multiple of $24$.

The sum of the divisors of $1200$ that are multiples of $24$ is $(2^3+2^4)(3^1)(5^0+5+5^2)(7^0)(11^0)...$

Notice we have eliminated any choices for generating terms in the sum that are not multiples.

We get $(24)(3)(31)=2232$

$3844-2232=\boxed{1612}$.

Comment: if you want to state the general case then you can say something like: the factorization of $x$ is $\Pi_{n=1}^k p_n^{E_n}$ where $p_n$ is the nth prime number, $k$ is number of distinct prime factors of $x$, and $E_n$ is the exponent of that prime number in the prime factorization of $x$. Then the sum of divisors $S(x)=S(\Pi_{n=1}^k p_n^{E_n})=\Pi_{n=1}^k \frac{p_n^{E_n+1}-1}{p_n-1}$

Comment: see the thing is i don't know any of that

Comment: i can barely subtract 10-5 @Χpẘ

Comment: Understood. BTW, $\Pi$ means the [product of a sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication#Products_of_sequences)

Comment: just like how $\sum$ means the sum

Comment: $\product$ hmmm

Comment: $\pi$ $\Pi$ what

Comment: Yes like $\Sigma$ is sum.